# What is the font used on Console.app in macOS Sierra?

Tags: mac, font, macos, console

Looks like Console.app went through some changes in macOS Sierra. I really liked the font used in that app but can't find it anywhere in the app (probably they disabled changing the font altogether).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font used in the Console.app on macOS Sierra is the `SFMono-Regular` font.

This can be found in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts`

More versions can be found in Xcode8 directories for example here:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Fonts/`

Comment: Is `SFMono-Regular` the *new* font in OSX Sierra or is it the old font used in El Capitan and earlier? (I prefer the old font.. it's not as "fat").

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz As far as I know, SFMono-Regular was introduced in Sierra.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the old font was?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I remember that `menlo` was used in the Xcode app.

Comment: Strange... I have a MacBook Pro and an iMac, both recently upgraded to Sierra, and both say the font is `Monaco 10pt`. The two fonts look different on the two screens. :( One has antialiasing enabled and the other does not. Changing that setting does not affect the iMac screen while the MacBook font gets very ugly and fuzzy when enabled. Hmm.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz please ask a question on a main page. There's no point to discuss this in comments. Maybe someone else has a solution for this.

Comment: In macOS Mojave, the font found within `Console.app` is `SFMono-Regular.otf`.